# Console application in docker not working

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am trying to learn docker practically. To start with I have created a simple .net core 3.1 console application. This application simply writes a message in a text file in a specific location. I have created a docker image from it and then docker container from the image. When I run the docker container, it runs and stops successfully.

The docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish App/

WORKDIR /App

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

I also checked the logs using command "docker logs container_id". But it returns nothing.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker runs a process inside a container, when that process ends the container stops and end too. As the process in your container only writes something and exits, the container exits and stops too.

Also the text file is written in the container file system. So you will not be able to see it in your host, unless you use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Try printing the string to standard output instead

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion to write the content on standard output worked. I tried the example given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows to write the data in the console window and view. It worked. I will try with the volumes approach as well.